# jquery prepend plus fadein not working with version 1.8

Tags: jquery

a part of my code uses the html returned from the ajax call to be prepend to a div. but when i updated to jquery version 1.8, it stopped working in firefox thought it works perfect in chrome and other browsers.

my code is

```
$("#content").prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow'));
```

and the error in firefox is

> NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg
>   0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

i tired figuring out the problem and found that using `$("#content").prepend(html);` without fadeIn works `fadeIn('slow')` is causing the problem . Can anyone help me with a code in which i can use both and works fine with jquery version 1.8 and firefox.

Comment: Why not `$("#content").prepend($(html)).fadeIn('slow');`?

Comment: @jeschafe that is not equivalent.  You are fading all of `#content` and not just what is in `html`.  I think you mean something similar to adaneo's answer.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Ahh you are correct and yes that's what I was going for.  Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$(html).prependTo("#content").fadeIn('slow');
```

`$(html)` would of course have to be initially hidden for it to work ?

If you're really trying to fade in the `#content` element, you could do:

```
$('#content').prepend(html).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Agreed.  The original code is a bit odd.  It makes more sense to call `fadeIn` after it has been added to the DOM.

Comment: its working but the fadeIn is not working . any solution for that

Comment: this seem to work '$('#content').prepend(html).fadeIn('slow');' please add this to your asnwer so that i can accept it and it could help someone too . thanks for helping

Comment: But that would fade in the `#content` element, not the `$(html)` element, and would not be equal to the code in your question at all, but if it works you obviously have hidden the `#content` element, and that is what you're really are trying to fade in.

Comment: strange . its working fine . emm i am trying to fade in the html result after ajax call into #content div . according to this code it would prepend the html into #content plus fading it during prepending

Comment: Well, yes! It would prepend the `html` to `#content` and then fade it in as you say, but it would fade in `#content`, not `$(html)`, but since `$(html)` is inside `#content` it will still give the same effect, and that is obviously what you are trying to do as you have initially hidden `#content`, it's just not very clear from the code in your question.

Comment: so the code i am using is right ? or should i find some other way out?

Comment: No, the code is fine if it's working the way you'd like it to work.